# Retrieve child element without knowing the parent

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it's possible to get the name of the objet1 & objet2 without specifying 'objet1' & 'objet2'?

```
let tableauObj = [ 
objet1: {name: Albert}, 
objet2: {name: Florence}]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! All parts of your post should be written in English, including the title.

Comment: What you've posted isn't syntactically valid, so no.

Comment: The code you show is not syntactically correct JavaScript code. Please fix that first.

Comment: Use `Object.values(tableuObj)` after you fix it to be an object instead of an array.

Comment: Use Object.values() to turn the object into an array of the values

Comment: Unclear how you are trying to get them. What are you doing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to objects in an array by their index within the array. Click these links to learn more about [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in JavaScript.

```js
let tableauObj = [ 
{name: "Albert"}, 
{name: "Florence"}];

// The object with the name property of "Albert"
// is at index zero of the tableauObj array:
console.log(tableauObj[0].name);

// The object with the name property of "Florence"
// is at index one of the tableauObj array:
console.log(tableauObj[1].name);
```